# SSRS has a hidded group statement that is not in the dataset query. How to find it?

Tags: reporting-services

REPORT BUILDER 3.0

I am changing the data sets of our reports to standard data sets. In some cases the names of fields have changed. Despite changing the cells to the new names I get an error of:

"The Group expression for the grouping ‘companyname’ refers to the field ‘companyname’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.

"companyname" changed to CompanyName and *there is no group by companyname in the Dataset SQL*. How can I change that in SSRS?

Comment: if you change dataset names or the returned columns, you must changes all dependencies in the report, list, groups, matrix, etc.

Comment: Have you looked in the Row Groups and Column Groups sections at the bottom of the Report Builder window? Perhaps you have groupings there which reference the old field names, rather than a `GROUP BY` clause in your dataset definition itself?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've faced this, the places to check are:

- Row Groups
- Column Groups
- Header text boxes for interactive sorting

9 times out of 10 when I can't find it, it's in the interactive sorting on text boxes.
[image: Interactive Sorting]